# Как отобразить правильно текст html?

Tags: html, кодировка

Открывая в vs code шаблон у меня не отображается текст,я так понимаю проблемы с кодировкой,но в браузере всё отображается,как исправить?

```
<tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="hd_companyname">
                        <h1><a href="">��������� �������</a></h1>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="hd_txarea">
                        <span class="tel">8 (495) 212-85-06</span>  <br/>   
                        ����� ������ <span class="workhours">��������� � 9-00 �� 18-00</span>                       
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:232px">
                        <form action="">
                            <div class="hd_search_form" style="float:right;">
                                <input placeholder="�����" type="text"/>
                                <input type="submit" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Открыть файл в текстовике и сохранить с кодировкой UTF-8
Должно помочь